# Unable to insert new record in SQLite using Emulators

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I am trying to develop a small app where at the end of the flow which needs to insert one row of data in SQLite database.

Following is the code which i am trying for insert:

```
SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
values.put("UserId",1);
values.put("A",scoreValues.get("I"));
values.put("B",scoreValues.get("J"));
values.put("C",scoreValues.get("K"));
db.insert("ScoreTbl",null,values);
db.close();
```

When the above code is run, i am getting an Error message,

> W/FileUtils: Failed to
>   chmod(/data/user/0/com.abc.xyz/databases/mydatabase.db: :
>   android.system.ErrnoException: chmod failed: EPERM

Can somebody help me how to overcome this error?

Comment: try this.getWritableDatabase();

Comment: refer : https://github.com/devpack/android-python27/issues/7

Comment: Changed it to this.getWritableDatabase(); but still getting the same error. As it is write permission or chmod in Emulator, do we need to add anything in AndroidManifest some perssion etc...?

Comment: @MohammadAli, whatever solution mentioned in the link is almost not understandable for a newbie like me. Can you suggest anything else? If i install the app in any physical device, is there a chance of the code works well?

Comment: ya if u install in device then is work perfect becoz i'll use this already in my device @Uday

Comment: You might want to do a search for *android.system.ErrnoException: chmod failed: EPERM* and have a look. One thing is that it's not a getReadableDatabase/getWriteableDatabase issue as the latter will in most circumstances return a **writeable** database [see - getReadableDatabase](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteOpenHelper.html#getReadableDatabase()). What it will do is attempt to return a readable database when a writeable database cannot be returned.

Comment: @MohammadAli, what i observed is, it is complaining the same error even i manually add data and trying to read from that table. Is it happen like that or am i making something mess here?

Comment: this is the perfect code and also see the ##Vikash code both are perfect @Uday

Comment: Can someone help here? Initially i have one table and i was able to access table data. Later i tried to create another table through code and got above error. So i created that table manually and tried to access the data, but still getting the same above error message. Can someone help how to overcome that error, because now i manually created table and data. Here to read data, i am using "this.getReadableDatabase();"

Comment: By bad, i forgot to upload the updated database back to the emulator after manually adding table. Now i am able to access all tables. Thanks everyone for your support.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

change this..

```
SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
```

to

```
SQLiteDatabase db    = this.getWritableDatabase();
```

`getReadableDatabase()` method Create and/or open a database.

`getWritableDatabase()` method Create and/or open a database that will be used for reading and writing.

check [Docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteOpenHelper.html)

Comment: Changed it to this.getWritableDatabase(); but still getting the same error. As it is write permission or chmod in Emulator, do we need to add anything in AndroidManifest some perssion etc...?

Comment: there is a basic SQLite tutorial which you can follow https://www.androidhive.info/2011/11/android-sqlite-database-tutorial/

Answer (score 0):

the db class extends SQLiteOpenHelper and also create table then after used below code to insert data.

```
SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
values.put("UserId",1);
values.put("A",scoreValues.get("I"));
values.put("B",scoreValues.get("J"));
values.put("C",scoreValues.get("K"));
db.insert("ScoreTbl",null,values);
db.close();
```